# How to make aiogram finite state machine save state for messages, not for the whole chat?

Tags: python, aiogram

I'm working on a Telegram bot using **aiogram** and its finite state machine (FSM) module to manage user input. However, I've noticed that the FSM saves the state for the entire conversation, rather than for individual messages. This causes issues with InlineKeyboardMarkup messages.

For example, I have two handlers

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(state=State.start, text=State.tariffs._state)
async def tariffs(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    button1 = InlineKeyboardButton(State.course_1._description, callback_data=State.course_1._state)
    button2 = InlineKeyboardButton(State.course_2._description, callback_data=State.course_2._state)
    button3 = InlineKeyboardButton(State.course_3._description, callback_data=State.course_3._state)
    keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    keyboard.row(button1, button2, button3)
    
    await bot.edit_message_text(text=State.tariffs._text, 
                                message_id=callback_query.message.message_id, 
                                chat_id=callback_query.message.chat.id, 
                                reply_markup=keyboard)
    await State.tariffs.set()

@dp.callback_query_handler(state=State.start, text=State.mytariffs._state)
async def mytariffs(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    button1 = InlineKeyboardButton(State.mycourse_1._description, callback_data=State.mycourse_1._state)
    keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    keyboard.row(button1)
    
    await bot.edit_message_text(text=State.mytariffs._text, 
                                message_id=callback_query.message.message_id, 
                                chat_id=callback_query.message.chat.id, 
                                reply_markup=keyboard)
    await State.mytariffs.set()
```

If I receive two messages and I navigate to the "tariffs" state in one of them, I won't be able to access either the "tariffs" or "mytariffs" section in the other message.

Is there a way to modify the aiogram FSM so that it saves state for each message individually, rather than for the entire chat?

I tried to change dispatcher.py to save the message ID from CallbackQuery instead of the chat ID, but now it can't see what state it is set to

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: A message is a static thing.  Once sent, it never changes.  How can it possibly have state?  What would trigger a "state change"?

Comment: The message has been sent by a bot and includes navigation buttons. Pressing any of the buttons causes the bot to edit the message based on the current state and the button that was pressed.